# need equivalent query in SQLite

Tags: c#, linq, android-sqlite

what is the equivalent sqlite query of the following statement?

```
Data = _db.EMP_TRACKING.OrderBy(m => m.ID).Skip(page - 1).Take(PageSize)
```

Or

What will be the query for the following scenario??

Say, I have table with 100000 rows. First I want select 1-100, then 101-200 ......

Comment: Can't you view generated SQL when you execute the statement, or just do `Data.ToString()`? And it should be `page x PageSize - 1`.